# JS replace over multiple lines

Tags: javascript, regex

Using Javascript

I'd like to remove an email signature from a multiline string by using another string which contains the email signature like so...

```
const email = `<h1>Hi there</h1>
               <p>How are you?</p>
               <p>Bye</p>
               <div class="signature">
                  my number is 0343243
               </div>`

const signature = `<div class=signature>
                      my number is 0343243
                   </div>`
```

My desired result would be...

```
<h1>Hi there</h1>
<p>How are you?</p>
<p>Bye</p>
```

Comment: maybe `email.replace(signature, "")` ?!

Comment: @Jonasw can you explain how that would help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple replace function here. Here is the solution to your problem.

```js
var value = '<h1>Hi there</h1><p>How are you?</p> <p>Bye</p><div class="signature">my number is 0343243</div>'

var mask = '<div class="signature">my number is 0343243</div>'
alert(value.replace(mask,''));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had troubles working out how to do that over a multiline string rather than just a single, sorted it out in my answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to sort it out by converting the multiline string to a single line with something like...

```
const singleLineEmail = email.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
const singleLineSignature = signature.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

From there I was able to so a simple

```
const cleanEmail = singleLineEmail.replace(singleLineSignature, '')
```